# Laravel DomPDF Failed to load PDF document

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I tried to implement [Laravel Dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package to generate pdf from HTML. But everything works perfectly on MAMP. But when I tried the code on the production server then the DomPDF is not working and generating the error.

> Failed to load PDF document.

I even tried very basic example `PDF::loadHTML('Hello World!')->stream('download.pdf');` but no success.

I tried to check the log file too but there is no error generated in the log file. We are using Laravel 5.6.*, PHP 7.2 and Apache Server.

Comment: did you check to make sure you have all the same extensions enabled on both servers? ```php -m```

Comment: did you check on server if you got DOM and GD and MBString extensions installed/enabled? pls check all requirements at https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements

Comment: @Mfoo, I am checking if this is the problem.

Comment: @koalaok, these all extensions are installed and enabled on the server.

Comment: @jogesh_pi are you using the same browser for both tests? it could have to do with security related to the content type, it may be more "lax" on your local machine

Comment: @Mfoo, I tried with the same and with the different browswers too.

Comment: I am trying with very simple example ```PDF::loadHTML('Hello World!')->stream('download.pdf');``` to check if there is any security concern. But no luck

Comment: without chaining ->stream() ... does the problem persists? I think someway the content-type is wrong. You should check it in the browser inspector, for the answer. And manage it.

Comment: @koalaok, if i change stream to download, and open the pdf after saving then the same error i am getting